# Bridging the gap between hardware and software

Tags: binary, hardware

So, I've done a bit of programming in my day. Java, C#, C++, and I've always had a fascination with computers in general. One thing that I would really like to learn, and, what I think would really help my programming skills, is how software tells the hardware what to do.

I'm aware that's quite the tall order: I know that's different per language; per OS. I'm not asking for an actual answer, as much as I'm asking for a starting point. Also, if this is actually a waste of time, like, if it wouldn't really help my programming and/or wouldn't be worth it because it's a massive amount of stuff to learn and it would take years for it to actually pay off, saying that would be helpful too.

I can't escape the feeling that I'm asking a stupid question.

Comment: I've often wondered this myself, I'd like to see what answers you get! :)

Comment: It's not stupid at all but you should consider asking this on computer science page of SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of hardware design? Either studying it by reading up, or by actually designing your own hardware. You could buy yourself a Raspberry PI, or Arduino, or something else if you don't want to get your hands dirty. Use any of these options to get your hands on hardware, or even use something like Vbox and write your own operating system.

Some random thoughts to consider. And, no your question isn't a stupid one at all.

Answer (score 0):

What we commonly call hardware can be thought of as a (big) number of electrical devices that function according to some specific rules. By putting some electrons in the input(s), the output(s) will vary after after a fixed rule ( similar devices behave the same). The best known device is the transistor. Transistors can be connected in such a way that they perform logical functions, the most used being NAND ( not and). Using NAND gates any kind of logic can be(and is) implemented. To sum it up, hardware does logic functions by moving electrons around.

Now comes the interresting question. What is software? People tend to think that because there is thought involved in writing software, that it doesn't exist in the real world. Which isn't true. The program is stored in RAM* when you write it, effectively being a pattern of electrons. Now this pattern suffers some transformations ( compiler , assembler ), during those steps the pattern changes from something that is meaningfull to humans to something that can be used as input to the logic functions from above.

On a tangent: A RS flip flop is an interresting device. It uses two NAND blocks to create a memory cell.